# combobox selected item not working inside datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datagrid, combobox

I have a datagrid in which I put one column as TemplateColumn.

Here is my Datagrid:

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False"
          x:Name="MainDataGrid"
          ItemsSource="{Binding OrderItems}">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Width="230" Header="Product Name">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding ProductName,Mode=OneWay}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ComboBox 
                        Text="{Binding ProductName,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
                        <vw:CustomDatagrid />
                    </ComboBox>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

In the CellEditingTemplate I put one Combobox in that I put one UserControl .

Here is my UserControl:

```
<UserControl x:Class="RH_Maize.View.CustomDatagrid"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" Height="499" Width="560">
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot"  Width="560">
    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding FilterdItems}"
              SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedFilterItem,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
              x:Name="CustomDataGrid"
             >
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn MinWidth="150"
                                Header="Category"
                                Binding="{Binding CategoryName,Mode=OneWay}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn MinWidth="180"
                                Header="Item"
                                Binding="{Binding ProductName,Mode=OneWay}" />
            <DataGridTextColumn MinWidth="130"
                                Header="Rate"
                                Binding="{Binding Rate,Mode=OneWay}" />
            <DataGridHyperlinkColumn MinWidth="100" Header="Details"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

My requirement is :

When the Combobox text changes I populate the CustomDatagrid with Items ,user  can select an item from the CustomDatagrid, the selectedItem(ProductName) is displayed on the Combobox.

My viewModel:

```
public class ProductCartViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public ProductCartViewModel()
    {
        PopulateCustomGrid(string.Empty);
    }

    private string _productName;
    public string ProductName   
    {
        get { return _productName; }
        set
        {
            if (value != _productName)
            {
                _productName = value;
                PopulateCustomGrid(_productName);
                RaisePropertyChanged(() => ProductName);
            }
        }
    }

    private void PopulateCustomGrid(string productNameMatch)
    {
        List<ProductFilterModel> lstProduct = new List<ProductFilterModel>();
        using(var context=new MaizeEntities())
        {
            var items = from p in context.TblProducts
                        where p.ProductName.Contains(productNameMatch)
                        select p;


           foreach(var item in items)
           {
               ProductFilterModel product = new ProductFilterModel();
               product.CategoryName = item.TblProductCategory.CategoryName;
               product.ProductId = item.ProductId;
               product.ProductCode = item.ProductCode;
               product.ProductName = item.ProductName;
               product.Rate = item.PurchaseRate;

               lstProduct.Add(product);
           }
           FilterdItems = new ObservableCollection<ProductFilterModel>(lstProduct);
        }
    }
}
```

My problem:

When the user select an item from the CustomDataGrid the combobox.Text got the "RH_Maize.View.CustomDatagrid" text instead of ProductName .Whats wrong with my code ?

Comment: could you post a screenshot for the same, it is little difficult to understand the issue. appreciated if you could possibly narrow down the question to your issue only.

Comment: @pushpraj ,I created this based on this  post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24074846/wpf-custom-datagrid-inside-combobox

Comment: @Sheridan ,I created this based on this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24074846/wpf-custom-datagrid-inside-combobox

Comment: That still doesn't explain why. What's the point of using the `ComboBox` at all if there is only ever one item?

Comment: @Sheridan , my requirement is ,when the user type something on the combobox inside the Main datagrid ,I want to populate the items based on the text of the combox into an customDataGrid,from which the user can select an item

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you to go for popup approach which look like a textbox with a button at end to open popup

So the template for the column will have a textbox where user can type and a popup where you can host child controls (datagrid in your case)

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <TextBox x:Name="text" />
    <ToggleButton Grid.Column="1"
                  Content="..."
                  x:Name="toggle" />
    <Popup PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=text}"
           IsOpen="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=toggle}">
        <Border Background="White">
            <TextBlock Text="your child control here, eg datagrid" />
        </Border>
    </Popup>
</Grid>
```

popup will be controlled by the button at the end you can also make it open by clicking the text box too

inside popup you can place your data grid etc.

**DataGrid in popup**

```
    <Popup PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=text}"
           IsOpen="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=toggle}">
        <Border Background="White">
            <vw:CustomDatagrid SearchKey="{Binding Text, ElementName=text}}"/>
        </Border>
    </Popup>
```

binding a assumed property `SearchKey` in your custom control `CustomDatagrid` to `Text` property of TextBox, this binding will push the value of text box to control where you can perform filter search or other logic to populate your data in grid.

**Clarification on introduction of property `SearchKey`**

`When the Combobox text changes I populate the CustomDatagrid with Items ,user can select an item from the CustomDatagrid, the selectedItem(ProductName) is displayed on the Combobox.`

to me it mean that you need to pass the user typed text to the CustomDatagrid and populate the grid, and when user select an item from data grid you want to display it in combo box. so I this assumed property SearchKey, which will help you to pass the text data in a MVVM way.

You can choose to have any name for the property, you'd we able to populate the grid as long as you receive the text typed by user

you may choose to pass in the view model also in order to set properties, execute some methods etc.

Comment: why the SearchKey in CustomGrid,whats the purpose of it

Comment: ,thank you for your time ,but I dont understand the SearchKey <vw:CustomDatagrid SearchKey="{Binding Text, ElementName=text}}"/>  is I need to create a dependency property or something

Comment: you got is correct, you can create this dependency property in your custom grid, then you can simply bind it to textbox and it will change when user will type in the textbox and you can attach a property changed handler then when it triggers you can populate the grid based on the value.

Comment: I implemented your approach, but now I got stucked,what if I want to return multiple values say ProductId,ProductCode,ProductName,UnitPrice etc when select an Item from the CustomGrid,send back to the Main grid how do I  achieve this ,Is I need to create as many dependency property ,I appreciate your help

Comment: You could pass back the instance of your model class (i.e. Product) for the same with just one property instead of passing all values separately.

Comment: but how do I pass that from my CustomDataGridViewModel to MainDatagridViewModel

Comment: I assume the items in comobox are the products. So you can bind the SelectedItem of the combobox to the property in the grid viewmodel which will handle the grid. BTW Is it possible for you to send a working sample of your code so I can see what you are trying to achieve and at same time I can give you exact changes instead of hit and trial approaches.

Comment: here you go https://www.sendspace.com/file/i1084v I've placed a button `Add to cart` in the popup grid which will bring the selected product in the main grid. look for `SEND TO GRID:` in the project's code to find where I modified. You may choose to do it on product selection, double click etc. I just did a sample, you may need to write in your logic to get desired result.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55689/discussion-between-angel-and-pushpraj).